# How to disable admin prompt in start-up .bat-file (Windows 10)?

Tags: windows, batch-file

So I'm running a check to see if my laptop's docked or not, if it is I'll disable my iGPU by running the following batch command:

```
@echo off
echo *** Disabling NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 with Max-Q Design ***
devmanview.exe /disable "NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 with Max-Q Design"
echo *** Done ***
```

The issue is, that as this'll run every time at start-up, I don't want to have to respond to the UAC prompt (for devmanview.exe). Is there a way I can either prevent this prompt from triggering, or auto-answer it?

Thanks!

(Here's the full script for anyone interested:)

```
:: See if NAS is connected locally
Dir \\169.254.1.2\Docker\CheckFile.txt
If %ErrorLevel% EQU 0 GoTo FileSpecifiedIsHere
GoTo ItIsntHere
Pause This line is never reached

:FileSpecifiedIsHere
::Do whatever I want to if the one specified is detected
Start "Starting the application" /MIN "C:\DisableGTX1650.bat"
GoTo EndThisBatch

:ItIsntHere
::Do whatever I want to if the one specified is not detected
Start "Starting the application" /MIN "C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUSTOR\EZ Connect\EasyConnect.exe"
Start "Starting the application" /MIN "C:\EnableGTX1650.bat"
GoTo EndThisBatch

:EndThisBatch
```

Comment: Are you wanting a way to bypass, from a simple batch script, Windows security? If so then there'd be little point to the Security, if it could be simply worked around by any script kiddie. If you wanted to auto answer the UAC prompt then you cannot do that directly from the batch script either because batch files do not interact with GUI applications. What you should be doing, instead of a basic start up script, is running your script as a scheduled task, with appropriate privileges, that way elevation wouldn't be needed, and a UAC prompt would not occur.

Comment: I am running the 2nd script via a scheduled task, but as it calls on another program (in the 1st script) I'm still getting the prompts